# Can't import NAudio.Lame

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, using, naudio

I am unable to do

```
using NAudio.Wave;
using NAudio.Lame;
```

Visual Studio says:

```
The type or namespace 'Lame' does not exist in the namespace 'NAudio'
```

I installed via **NuGet** and I rebuilt, rebooted, cleaned and did all that stuff but it still doesn't work
I am quite new to .Net so maybe I just missed something very obvious.

I am using **.Net Core 3.0** in a **WPF Application** with

Comment: Afaik, NAudio.Lame is a separate nuget package from NAudio itself. Do you have it installed?

Comment: yes sure i have it installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at https://github.com/Corey-M/NAudio.Lame/issues/33
The NuGet package is not "full" ready for .Net Core. However, the author relased a the pre-release package **v1.1.0-pre3**, which worked for me. You must configure NuGet to consider also pre-releases to see it (if you use the GUI).